# How to get the item inside table particular column

Tags: php, laravel

i have this attendance table how do i get the status is equal to [A and P] only 
here is my controller;

```
 $atnds = DB::table('attendances')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
                     ->where(['status' => ['P','A']])
                     ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->where('lead_id', '=', $id)
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a condition to check wheather `A` or `P` is marked then use `whereIn`

```
->whereIn('status', ['P','A'])
```

I Guess people would be either `A` Absent or `P` Present, not both.